# How to make gedit the default app for HTML files in Ubuntu 20/Files explorer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, html, gedit

I would like to always open HTML files with gedit when I click on them in the built in Files app in Ubuntu 20. I know you can choose the application to open with when you right click but this is a bit long winded. So I'd like gedit to be the default app for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar application list **in the file's "Properties" window** – if you change the default app there, the change will be persistent.